# SVN: Is it possible get a file locked as soon as the user checkout the file from SVN repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a particular requirement.
I want that as soon as the user checkouts a file, that file should get locked with the name of that user and then no other user should be able to checkout that file until the lock is released. I want to do this for a few binary files which cant be merged after simultaneous editing by various developers.
There is a property called svn:needs-lock but it  does not locks the file it only makes it read-only and does not allow to save the file after all the editing has been done which is a waste of both time and efforts.
Is there a method through which i may be able to create a hook which gets triggered as soon as a checkout takes place. And in that hook I may lock the file so that no one else is able to edit it until I commit and the lock is released.

Comment: You misunderstood how svn:needs-lock is supposed to work. The read-only restriction is revoked as soon as you lock the file.

Comment: Hi Doc Brown, What I think is that when we checkout a file which has an svn:needs-lock property on it then we are not able to edit the file unless and until we lock the file. What I want is that when we checkout a file then it should automatically get locked. Please suggest now or correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: If you could only get a lock by checking out, as far as I understand you correctly that would mean you would not get a working copy of any files you do not want to change. Is it that what you really want? In a typical project based on multiple files (for example, a compiled language project), you need these files, at least as a read-only copy.

Comment: Perhaps it is only a problem of words - tell everyone "lock = checkout", and checkout "get a read-only-copy", and they will happy?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a exlusive lock on a file only based on a checkout. What you can do is put the svn:needs-lock property on the file. The result is to have the file read-only in the working copy and a reminder to get a lock first before doing changes. Subversion works based on the "copy-modify-merge" model. The strickt locking paradigm is used by other versions control systems like ClearCase but not by Subversion.

Comment: I have never worked with Clear Case for myself, but AFAIK Clear Case works with a special file system. That means that a locking scheme where a checkout or lock actually blocks the file completely for all other users may be possible with that (can someone confirm that?). SVN, where the working copy resides on your local drive, cannot actively access the working copies of other users from the server side. However, the "needs-lock" function is a pragmatic alternative to get around this restriction, good enough for a hell lot of SVN users.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use another version control system that uses exclusive locking.
SVN isn't appropriate for the scenario you have in mind.

Comment: Other version control system with exclusive locking (like PVCS) work just like SVN with the needs-lock property. The only difference is that PVCS has exclusive-locking as default model.

Comment: I've had the displeasure of working with at least one VCS where a locked file couldn't even be read by other users, but I can't for the life of me remember which it was.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to write a script/program than runs when you try to open this type of files. The script would check whether the file is read-only (you don't use CD-disks often isn't it?). In this case it will lock the file (or show an error message) and launch the editor.

Comment: No we dont use CD-disks.  By scripts you want to say that i should make use of hooks? If that is the case then there are no hooks available in SVN that get triggered on checkout. I mean to say that there is no post-checkout hook in SVN. So how to write a script that checks whether the file is read-only on checkout and lock it as soon as we checkout. Please suggest how to trigger a script on checkout. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No I don't meant SVN hook scripts - they are server side. I meant that when you open file of some type some command is run. I suggest to replace it with script. In windows this command can be changed in a registry. The read-only check shouldn't hit when you open regular files (not in the SVN repository) so this scripts shouldn't affect much your normal editor usage. And you can always add exceptions to the script if this is not the case.